# Can I change the time zone of the GCP Billing Report from Pacific time zone to another time zone?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

The documentation states that the Google Cloud Billing Report defaults to the Pacific time zone. I would like to see the GCP Billing Report change to our local time zone instead of the Pacific time zone, but I haven't found a way to do this yet. is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

The Google Cloud Billing reports use the Pacific Time Zone. The time zone cannot be changed.

Google Cloud supports creating feature requests.

[Feature requests](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)

Comment: Does Google Cloud change based on Daylight saving time ? Or does it stay the same relative to UTC throughout the year

Comment: @Weebe - I do not know for sure. The definition of Pacific Time means following time changes.

Comment: "... observes daylight saving time shifts in the United States." as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports)